# How to export CSV files that contains numbers with thousand operators in python (pandas)?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I have this `numbers.csv`:

`Title/BOLA;"Total/1,333.903";`

And I'm running this piece of code on it:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("numbers.csv", sep=";",header=None)
print(df1)
df1 = df1.stack().str.split('\s*/\s*', expand=True)
df1 = df1.reset_index(level=1, drop=True).set_index(0, append=True)[1].unstack()  
df1.to_csv("test.csv")
df1 = df1.stack().str.split('\s*/\s*', expand=True)
df1 = df1.reset_index(level=1, drop=True).set_index(0, append=True)[1].unstack()
df1.to_csv("final_csv.csv")
```

`print(df1)` returns:

```
                   0                                               1   2
0  Title/BOLA  Total/1,333.903 NaN
```

When I'm saving into `final_csv.csv` the number `1,349.098` turns to `1`. I would like to save the number `1349.098`, instead. Can you help me?

Comment: The answers look like they should work. What is the intent of the string operations in lines 3 and 4 of the code? The problem might be an unexpected result rather than a problem with pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are reading in the column 1 as a string and then writing it back as a string. This means it will continue to carry the commas forward. In `to_csv("test.csv")`, you are not specifying a separator so it is defaulting to a comma. I'm assuming 349.098 is showing up in the next column. You can get around this by specifiying a separator in `df1.to_csv("test.csv", sep=';')`, but make sure your code is doing what you think it is doing first.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get where I would specify `df1.to_csv("test.csv", sep=';')`

Comment: That would replace your `df1.to_csv("test.csv")` line.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `thousands=','` flag while reading the csv data. See param's [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv)

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("numbers.csv", sep=";", header=None, thousands=',')
```

**CSV OUTPUT:**

```
Title,Total
BOLA,"1,333.903"
```

Comment: This would fix the problem that I mentioned earlier and probably does what the asker really wants, but didn't ask for. (You are the hero Gotham needs.)

Comment: see working demo here: https://repl.it/@SanyAhmed/EarnestTatteredRepo and let me know is that you wanted or not?

Comment: @Curious_Mind the problem is when I open the CSV it shows only `1` because it is interpreting commas as a breaker. That's why I would like to OUTPUT: `BOLA,"1333.903"`. I added the full code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to quote the number field during writing and reading back, since it contains the ',' separator character:

```
pandas.to_csv(..., quoting=1) # for QUOTE_ALL
pandas.to_csv(..., quoting=0) # for QUOTE_MINIMAL
pandas.read_csv(..., quoting=...) # ditto
```

See the 'quoting section' in the doc pages [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: It's returning `TypeError: "quoting" must be an integer`

Comment: Fixed. As the docpages say, pandas uses integer codes for quoting: `quoting=QUOTE_MINIMAL (0), QUOTE_ALL (1), QUOTE_NONNUMERIC (2) or QUOTE_NONE (3)`, whereas Python builtin csv module uses those constant names `csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL` etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you have this dataframe after line 4 in your code:

```
df1 = df1.reset_index(level=1, drop=True).set_index(0, append=True)[1].unstack()
print(df1)

    Title   Total
0   BOLA    1,333.903
```

Then you could remove the comma and convert the string to a float:

```
df1['Total'] = df1['Total'].str.replace(',', '').astype(float)
```

And the result looks as follows:

```
    Title   Total
0   BOLA    1333.903
```